Unable to host the application to https
I recently updated my ASP.NET web API from targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 to 4.7. The application runs perfectly fine locally, but I'm facing issues when deploying it to a Windows Server 2022 VM.
Here's what I've done so far:

I published the application to a folder.
Manually copied the publish folder to the VM.
Connected the VM to IIS and deployed the application.

However, I am unable to run the application on the server but can run it locally from vs at the same I am able run previous version of API that hosted in another port. I have ensured that .NET Framework 4.8 is installed on the server, which I understand should support .NET 4.7 applications.
I'm not sure what could be causing the issue or how to troubleshoot it further. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
network call to the API
steps I did

I've ensured that .NET Framework 4.8 is installed on the server. However, the application only works over HTTP, not HTTPS.

I've removed URL rewrite rules from the web.config, which seemed to help, but HTTPS still doesn't work.

I am using the same certificate that was used in the application when the project was targeting .NET Framework 4.5.


Certificate
Bindings
I have added correct port and certificate binding
Port binding and certificate assigning
And this certificate was working fine using the same certificate here is causing some issue

Crypto protocols and ciphers and how they are configured were completely changed in.NET 4.6.2.  You need to focus on that and review how it is configured. Doesn't matter that it worked in 2009 when .NET 4.5.2 was released. You also need to run a netmon packet capture on both ends and correlate the results. Lots of good information in there, eliminates guesswork.

"I'm unable to ..." or "facing issues" are not usable error descriptions. You need to be more specific of what exactly happens, i.e. detailed error description and messages.
